# Communication between servers in farm

Tags: 2010, farm, state

We have a farm with two load-balanced virtual machines. When a certain event happen in the application in one of the machines, I need to sync this with the rest of the machines in the farm, so that all running application processes are aware of the event.

I've considered creating a new custom list to store these messages and have the application poll this list with a certain interval, but is there any strategy that could enable real-time communication between the processes?

Is there some shared context for the machines in a farm that I could use for global communication?

Comment: Can you provide more information about what you need (the context) and what you're attempting to do? What is this 'event' you need to hook onto?

Comment: @TrevorSeward More specifically, I need to cache information about changes in a list. This cache need to be synchronized across all servers in the farm.